# QTableView timer click and doubleclick event

Tags: python, pyside2

I want to execute other command on click and double click. When doubleclick is executed, click does not want to be executed.

```
from PySide2 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui


class TestView(QtWidgets.QTableView):
    
    custom_clicked = QtCore.Signal(QtCore.QModelIndex)
    custom_double_clicked = QtCore.Signal(QtCore.QModelIndex)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(TestView, self).__init__(parent=parent)
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer(self)
        self.timer.setInterval(250)
        self.timer.setSingleShot(True)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.timeout)
        self.click_number = 0

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        super(TestView, self).mousePressEvent(event)
        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            self.index = self.indexAt(event.pos())
            self.click_number += 1
            if not self.timer.isActive():
                self.timer.start()

    def timeout(self):
        if self.click_number < 2:
            self.custom_clicked.emit(self.index)
        elif self.click_number > 1:
            self.custom_double_clicked.emit(self.index)
        self.click_number = 0


def click_command(index):
    print "single", index

def double_click_command(index):
    print "double", index

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    tableView = TestView()
    model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
    item = QtGui.QStandardItem()
    item.setData("test", QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole)
    model.setItem(0, item)
    tableView.setModel(model)
    tableView.setEditTriggers(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
    tableView.custom_clicked[QtCore.QModelIndex].connect(click_command)
    tableView.custom_double_clicked[QtCore.QModelIndex].connect(double_click_command)
    tableView.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

This code works well when there is no item.
However, it will break if you double-click the item.
Timer seems to be the cause, but I'm looking for a reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To detect the double click you should only use the mouseDoubleClickEvent so you only have to detect that it was not pressed a second time in a certain time:

```
class TestView(QtWidgets.QTableView):

    custom_clicked = QtCore.Signal(QtCore.QModelIndex)
    custom_double_clicked = QtCore.Signal(QtCore.QModelIndex)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(TestView, self).__init__(parent)
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer(self)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.timeout)
        self.timer.setInterval(
            QtGui.QGuiApplication.styleHints().mouseDoubleClickInterval()
        )
        self.timer.setSingleShot(True)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        super(TestView, self).mousePressEvent(event)
        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            self.index = self.indexAt(event.pos())
            self.timer.start()

    def mouseDoubleClickEvent(self, event):
        super(TestView, self).mouseDoubleClickEvent(event)
        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            index = self.indexAt(event.pos())
            self.custom_double_clicked.emit(index)
            self.timer.stop()

    def timeout(self):
        self.custom_clicked.emit(self.index)
```